# AppleScript: "Repeat" Loop Only Works With Variable

Tags: applescript, safari, error

Very curious as to why this works (the context is an open and activated/frontmost Safari window displaying the "Customize Toolbar" sheet):

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set entireContents to entire contents of sheet 1 of front window
        repeat with x in entireContents
            if class of x is image and description of x contains "My Extension" then
                set targetExtIconPos to position of image 1 of x
            else if class of x is image and description of x is "default set of toolbar items" then
                set defaultToolbarPos to position of x
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

but changing `repeat with x in entireContents` to `repeat with x in entire contents of sheet 1 of front window` throws an error (and does so even if parenthesis are utilized as in `repeat with x in (entire contents of sheet 1 of front window)`)?

The error I get is: `execution error: System Events got an error: Can’t make item 1 of entire contents of sheet 1 of window 1 of process "Safari" into type specifier. (-1700)`

This caused alot of headache before I randomly found it would work if I just assigned it to a var first...

Also is there a way to achieve what I am attempting here without using a loop at all? I feel like there is a way, but the syntax is just awfully hard and complex to figure out and nail down.

Comment: What happens if you include 'as list' after '(entire contents of sheet 1 of front window)'? I suspect that the system makes an incorrect assumption without it. As an aside, I'm unable to make the edit but the final 'end tell' is missing an 'l'.

Comment: @Mockman, What's returned by `entire contents`, even if only a single _item_, is already a _list_, so there is no need to use `as list` in this use case.

Comment: That makes sense but perhaps at the time something is calculated, it isn't taken into account. For me, when I do not explicitly include the 'as list', I get the error mentioned in the OP; when I include 'as list', I get a list and the repeat loop runs to completion. Applescript has its quirks, this may be one of them.

Comment: @Mockman appending `as list` does fix the issue, even without any parenthesis surprisingly. Just found out that changing it to `repeat with x in (get entire contents of sheet 1 of front window)` also fixes the error, so I believe these 2 expr are resolving to the same thing (unlike my original attempt at inlining the expr which is, perhaps, resolving to something else). I guess the original expression is an 'object specifier' or something, and I guess using `get` resolves it to a value? & maybe setting it to a var does the same, as does the `as list` explicit coercion? Why isn't this implicit?

Comment: Regarding the 'set as var', I believe that by putting this on its own line, it forces the subsequent line to work with the resolved expression. Why this doesn't occur otherwise, I'm not sure. 'get' should be implicit but I don't know whether this is reliably so.

Comment: @Mockman, The _code_ in the OP ran without error when I tested it and checked to see that `entire contents` was indeed a _list_. The fact that both the OP and you got errors is why so often I have to ask questions in the comments to the OP  like What version of **macOS**?, What version of **AppName**?, etc. as especially with **AppleScript** this makes a difference as it's not uncommon for each _update_, and more so each _upgrade,_ to break _code_ that works without issue on a different version of the **OS** or **App**.

Comment: @user3439894 That's sometimes the reason why I sort of answer some questions in comments rather than writing up a proper answer. It's not always possible to recreate or even know the environment. I don't ask questions but I wonder if there isn't —shouldn't be— something in the question process that would prod the questioner into including further relevant information; and ideally smart enough to not ask for details that aren't meaningful, or it would be a chore.

Comment: @user3439894 Sorry if it wasn't worded clearly but the code-quoted block in my original post does work. My question and issue was simply why the list HAD to be set to a var first (`entireContents` in this example) before the loop would work without error (i.e. the variable assignment is required and the code to retrieve the list cannot be inlined into the loop statement). I had decided to ask this question and then later, right b4 posting the question, I found that workaround. I posted the question anyway in hopes of furthering my knowledge of AppleScript.